# Menor valor en una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy calculando la distancia de un punto a otros puntos y los guardo en una matriz, como puedo obtener el valor minimo tomando la distancia que contiene, deberia de mostrar de ese dato encontrado
la distancia el nombre y la direccion del menor valor

```
lista=[]
lista += [distancia,nombre,direccion]
```

Los valores que se almacenan como ejemplo son los siguientes.

```
<class 'list'>: [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744']
<class 'list'>: [1.5000067783445622, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466']
<class 'list'>: [4.6825980651789, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890']
<class 'list'>: [0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147']
```

etc..

Gracias por la ayuda.

**Edit:**

```
for lugar in busquedajson['results']:

        nombre=lugar['name']
        direccion=lugar['vicinity']

        #Point one
        latJson = lugar['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lonJson = lugar['geometry']['location']['lng']

        distancia = gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(latJson,lonJson,r[1],r[0])

        metros = int(float(distancia))

        lista=[]
        lista += [metros,nombre,direccion]

        #archivolugares.write(lugar['name'] + ',' + str(lugar['geometry']['location']['lng']) \
        #+ ',' + str(lugar['geometry']['location']['lat']) + '\n')

minimo = min ( ((i , lista[ i ]) for i in range ( 0 , len ( lista ) , 3 )) , key=itemgetter ( 1 ) )[ 0 ]
print ( lista[ minimo:minimo + 3 ] )
```

Comment: Deberiás aclarar mejor lo que tienes y cómo creas la lista, por lo que muestras estas concatenando listas, algo muy ineficiente (usa `list.append` o `list.extend` en su lugar) y además con `lista += [distancia,nombre,direccion]` no creas una matriz (listas anidadas) simplemente añades los tres elementos a tu lista, es decir, obtendrías `[distancia1, nombre1 , direccion1, distancia2, nombre2, direccion2, ...]`, no `[[distancia1, nombre1 , direccion1], [distancia2, nombre2, direccion2], ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero que administres los elementos de otra forma, como una lista de listas, algo así:

```
lista=[]
lista.append([0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744'])
lista.append([1.5000067783445622, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466'])
lista.append([4.6825980651789, 'AAYPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890'])
lista.append([0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147'])
```

En cuyo caso la solución sería usar [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) combinado con [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) de la siguiente forma:

```
lista = [
          [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744'],
          [1.5000067783445622, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466'],
          [4.6825980651789, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890'],
          [0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147']
        ]

from operator import itemgetter
print(min((e for e in lista),key=itemgetter(0)))
```

Salida:

```
[0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744']
```

Básicamente a `min()` le pasamos cada sublista completa, pero le decimos que la búsqueda del mínimo lo haga solo sobre el primer elemento de cada lista.

Ahora si mantienes tu estructura:

```
lista=[]
lista += [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744']
lista += [1.5000067783445622, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466']
lista += [4.6825980651789, 'AAYPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890']
lista += [0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147']
```

Que es una única lista con todos los valores uno atrás del otro, esto es algo un poco más complejo de administrar, por ejemplo para acceder a la distancia debemos iterar de a tres elementos, pero eventualmente también podemos manejarlo con una solución similar a la anterior solo que un poco más compleja:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lista = [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744',
        1.5000067783445623, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466', 
        4.6825980651789, 'AAYPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890', 
        0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147'
        ]

minimo = min(((i, lista[i]) for i in range(0,len(lista),3)),key=itemgetter(1))[0]
print(lista[minimo:minimo+3])

> [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744']
```

Con `(i, lista[i]) for i in range(0,len(lista),3)` generamos un conjunto de tuplas con el índice que apunta a la distancia y el valor de la misma. Aplicamos el `min()`de una forma similar al ejemplo anterior y llegamos a un valor del estilo `(0, 0.5989068259400513)` del cual solo nos interesa el índice que asignamos a `minimo`, por último hacemos un recorte (slice) de la lista tomando desde el índice dónde aparece el mínimo, solo tres valores `print(lista[minimo:minimo+3])`

Comment: Gracias patricio por la pronta respuesta y ayuda, cuando lo ejecuto tengo el siguiente error
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Debianitas, si, por que en realidad no tienes una lista de listas, mi confusión. Ahí edité la respuesta, igual voy a pensar una solución para tu estructura.

Comment: Patricio te comparto la porcion de codigo donde aplico tu solucion en la cual no tengo el error de antes pero no muestro el minimo si no el ultimo.

Comment: @Debianitas, cuidado, estás inicializando la lista dentro del ciclo con `lista=[]` esto te va a dejar siempre el último de los casos, por lo cual no es que te retorna el máximo, sino que la lista tiene un solo elemento, lleva la inicialización fuera del ciclo.

Comment: Mil gracias Patricio por tu tiempo quedo perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Completando el final de la respuesta de @Patricio-Moracho:

Hay un modo elegante para trocear y obtener el mínimo usando únicamente iteradores:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice

lista = [0.5989068259400513, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Alem 744',
        1.5000067783445623, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Tucumán 466', 
        4.6825980651789, 'AAYPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Parana 890', 
        0.9999068259400518, 'YPF - Torre Blanca', 'C1049AAP, Lavalle 147'
        ]

it = iter(lista)
troceo = (list(islice(it,3)) for j in range(4))
minimo = min(troceo, key=itemgetter(0))
```

....